# Renaming report server url

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

i have set a sql report server [ssrs 2008 r2] and the url is like this>

http://Computer-name/ReportServer

I actually need the change the  "Computer name" part, should that be done in asp.net ? i've tried using urlroot from the reporting service configuration file and it did not work.

Thanks a lot!
Bruno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer-name is the hostname or network name. You'd have to either change it or use your local DNS to forward traffic to say http://reports/ReportServer